# выделить строку в диапазоне при выдачи значений в HTML

Tags: google-apps-script

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста ,как выделить  нужную строку при выдаче (изменить цвет букв)  например 5-ю (номер строки изменяется)
вот что у меня сейчас :

.gs

```
function doGet(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:F" + sheet.getLastRow());
var strn = range.getValues()
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('images');
template.strn = strn;

return template.evaluate();
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>


    <?

    for(var i=0; i < strn.length; i++ ) { ?>

    <tr>

     <? for(var j=0; j < strn[i].length; j++) { ?>  

    <td> <?=strn[i][j]?> </td>


    <?}?>

     </tr>
   <? }

    ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вопрос решил самостоятельно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Вариант 1

В данном случае, достаточно изменить только html-файл

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>

      <?for(var i=0; i < strn.length; i++ ) { ?>

      <tr>

        <? for(var j=0; j < strn[i].length; j++) { ?>

        <td <? if(i == 5){ ?> style="color:red"<? } ?>>
          <?=strn[i][j]?>
        </td>

        <? } ?>

      </tr>
      <? } ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Добавлено условие для проверки номера строки

```
<td <? if(i == 5){ ?> style="color:red"<? } ?>>
```

## Вариант 2

Но это очень сложно читать и сопровождать. Все же, лучше воспользоваться советами разработчиков и использовать асинхронный метод получения данных, и на его основе формировать страницы [Class google.script.run (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

### Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('images');
  return template.evaluate();
}

function getData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID');
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange('A1:F' + sheet.getLastRow());
  return range.getDisplayValues();
}
```

### images.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <table id="table">
  </table>
  <script>
    var table = document.getElementById('table');

    function onSuccess(data) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        if (i == 5) tr.style.color = 'red';
        for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
          var td = document.createElement('td');
          var txt = document.createTextNode(data[i][j]);
          td.appendChild(txt);
          tr.appendChild(td);
        }
        table.appendChild(tr);
      }
    }

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getData();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за развернутый ответ! я к сожалению прочитал его только сейчас сори !  Вопрос решил первым вариантом но не так красиво как вы. просто  добавил условие в сам цикл.<? } else {?>
        <td> <p style=    итд. Спасибо Вам сейчас бьюсь над другим вопросом опубликую его в этом форуме.

Comment: @AlexanderBaskakov, можно отметить ответ как решение.

Comment: поставил решение  Спасибо Вам!