# Как вывести изображения из диапзона в нужном формате

Tags: google-apps-script

Задача состоит в том ,что бы вывести картинки в ряд c форматированием по горизонтали с подписями . [Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/47rm8kwc/)

Есть диапазон A1-A10 (изображения) и B1-B10 (подписи) к ним

Сейчас у меня вот такой код который просто выводит картинки из диапазона.

Спасибо!

.gs

```
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A10");
var urls = range.getValues();
var range = sheet.getRange("B1:B10");
var strn = range.getValues();
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('images');
template.urls = urls;
template.strn = strn;
return template.evaluate();
```

images

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">

  </head>
  <body>

    <table> 

    <?

    for(var i=0; i < urls.length; i++ ) { ?>

    <tr> 

     <? for(var j=0; j < urls[i].length; j++) { ?>  

    <td>  <img src="<?=urls[i][j] ?>"  />  </td>


    <?}?>

     </tr>
   <? }

    ?>

    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var` в `php`? `<? for(var j`

Comment: Предполагаете ли вы использование какого-либо фреймворка или библиотеки для упрощения кода? Возможно, стоит изменить подход к организации клиентского кода как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/681069/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-html

Comment: Возможно! Я коротко опишу ,что я вообще отдаю клиенту 1) то что вы сделали то есть диапазон текст с выделенной строкой 2)под ними те картинки (миниатюры) которые относятся тексту.3) общие картинки по этой теме .У меня осталась  проблема с пунктом 2! Сейчас у меня вот такой вывод http://joxi.ru/KAgKqYec4JEx0A

Answer (score 1):

Ну и кто мешает тебе сделать так?

```
<div class="thumb">
<?php

    for($i=0; i < $urls.length; $i++ ) { ?>    

    <?php for($j=0; j < $urls[$i].length; $j++) { ?>  
    <figure>
        <img src="<?=$urls[$i][$j] ?>"  />
        <figcaption>Text1</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <?php } ?>


<?php }

?>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам ! я начинающий- это будет работать в google-apps-script я просто впервые сталкиваюсь  с <?php ?

Comment: @AlexanderBaskakov если ваш код работает то и это будет. посмотрите если что напишите

Comment: @ выдает ошибку , попробую сам разобраться .Спасибо Вам

Comment: @AlexanderBaskakov напишите ошибку

Comment: пишет в строке нет символа ; . но я думаю ,что не правильно вставляю классы из примера https://jsfiddle.net/47rm8kwc/ подскажите где посмотреть элементарный пример на эту тему?